# How to read cells without format in php Excel 2007

Tags: php, excel-2007, phpexcel

iam trying to read an Excel File with PHP Reader, i print the information with an echo of the Highest Row and the Highest Colum, but what i get is the last formatted Column&Row and what i need is just the last cell where data was inserted. Here is my code:

```
require_once '..\..\..\Common\PHPExcel_1.7.9_doc\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';

**code code code**

ReadExcelFile();

function ReadExcelFile(){

    $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
    $inputFileName = '../ExcelFiles/test.xlsx'; 
    $sheetname = 'Tabelle1'; 

    try {

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); 
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    } 
    catch(Exception $e) {       
        die('Error loading Excel file '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
    echo $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
    echo $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
}
```

Iam reading a very extense Macro that is modified once in a while externally (thats why i need to read just only to the last cell where has data) What i did was just a small copy of this excel file and the output was just

```
"254J"
```

But my last cell with data is about "210J". Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: that's the highest row/column that actually HAS something in it. e.g. it could be a single space character that's otherwise invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestDataRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
```

Comment: i tried with HighestDataRow(cleared the contents but nothing) but get the same output, i pressed ctrl+end and it takes me to 254J, but i have nothing in it just a colored cell because i need those formatted cells in case the macro gots bigger...

Comment: If getHighestDataRow/getHighestDataColumn returns the same cell reference, then that cell actually contains a value (even if it is an empty string) It means that there is an actual cell entry for that cell in the Excel file